# Managing customer's project and billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-billing

I have used Google Cloud for a while for my own projects. But this time I would like to deploy one of my customer's project to it. What is the best way to manage the fees?

1. Creating the project in my GC account and granting access to the customer to see the fees and send them invoices.
2. Creating the project in my GC account and somehow set their billing account to my project.
3. Creating the project in their GC account and ask for permissions to manage it.
4. Something else.

Which one is the correct solution, or what do you use? If the second solution is the good one, how can I achieve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review each option and consider everything from both you as the developer and the client who owns (pays for) the project. Think security and responsibility (legal, financial and ethical) when making these decisions.

**Option 1:**

> Creating the project in my GC account and granting access to the
>   customer to see the fees and send them invoices.

I would create a separate project for this customer and not mix their work into a project that has your own work. Granting the customer access to the billing information for a mixed account and then trying to separate items might take more time than it is worth. I don't recommend this method.

**Option 2:**

> Creating the project in my GC account and somehow set their billing
>   account to my project.

The customer will need to grant you access to their billing account which I do not recommend.  I would not grant access to my billing account to a third party. They could attach any project they want I would get the bill. I don't recommend this method.

**Option 3:**

> Creating the project in their GC account and ask for permissions to
>   manage it.

This is the best option. The project and billing are under the client's control and the client grants you the required permission such as Project Editor to your user identity. Project Ownership and Billing responsibility remains with the client and the client can grant and remove access to you anytime they want easily without a ripple effect of additional work.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, I accepted it!

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your preference, however, I would go with the second one. You can create the project for them, and they can create the billing account. You then can modify the billing account on the project you created by following the steps over [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project).

Nevertheless, as I mentioned this is all your preference so you can use any of the other approaches you mentioned too.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: @Andariel Option 2 will work except the customer will need to grant you access to their billing account which I do not recommend. The better option is #3 where the project and billing are under their control and the customer grants you required permission such as Project Editor to your user identity. Think security and responsibility (legal, financial and ethical) when making these decisions. I would not grant access to my billing account to a third party. They could attach any project they want I would get the bill.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you! In this case option 2 is problematic. I was not sure how this thing works. I thought it's possible to set their billing account only to one project. 

Ps.: I removed acceptance from this answer, if you post your solution as an answer then I can accept it!